# change the color of Sunday days in the calendar (it is red and needs to be any other color)

Tags: css, calendar

[image]

I have a calendar and I want to do deliveries on Sunday but when I enabled Sunday in the Admin panel for the calendar - it lets people select Sunday but the day is in the RED color which discourages people from ordering on that day...I looked in the Look At Code thingy in Chrome and found this:

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    **color: #960000;**
    background-color: #e1e1b6;
```

it points to myOWNdomain/index.php/checkout/onepage

How do I find out which file I need to change the color code in? Thank you so much for any help! :-*

I now think the color code should be f23f3f...I found this in main.css but changing it does not change anything...

***I contacted the calendar people and this is what they replied:***

```
The module is using calendar from Magento default
Please edit  /skin/frontend/base/default/css/bss/orderdeliverydate/calendar.css
Add:
.calendar thead .weekend{
 color: #000;
}
at the bottom of the file to change color of the text.
```

**I did that but it did not help with the days being red (it just changed the color of the word SUN to black from red.** I also put a **space** between **weekend** and **{** Please help...

This is the calendar.css file:

```
.calendar {
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.calendar tbody .disabled {
    /*border:1px solid #DDD;*/
}

.calendar tbody .disabled {
    color:#666;
    opacity:0.5;
    background: #FCFCFC none repeat scroll 0% 0%;

}
.calendar table {
    background: #F5F5F5 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border:none;
}

.calendar .button {
    border-color: #FFF #FFF #FFF #FFF;
}

.calendar thead .title {
    color:#666;
    background: #F5F5F5 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border:none;
}

.calendar tfoot .ttip {
    color:#666;
    background: #F5F5F5 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border:none;
}

.calendar thead .name {
    background: #F5F5F5 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:none;
}


.calendar thead .hilite {
    background: #E5E5E5 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    border-color: #FFF #DDD #DDD #FFF;
    border-width:2px;
    border-style:solid;
}

.calendar table .wn {
    border-right:1px solid #FFF;
    background-color: #F4F0E8 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
}


.calendar td.time {
    border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.calendar tbody .day {
    border:1px solid #FFF;
}

.calendar tbody td.selected {
    border-color: #FFF #BBB #BBB #FFF; 

}

.calendar tbody td.hilite {
    border-color: #FFF #BBB #BBB #FFF; 
    border-width:2px;
}
.calendar .nav {
    background:none;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

.bss-delivery-date #advice-required-entry-shipping_arrival_date_display {
    position:absolute;
    max-width:130px;
}

#shipping-method-buttons-container {
    margin-top:5px !important;
} 

.calendar thead .calendar-title {
    border-color:#FFF;
    background: #F5F5F5 none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    color: #666;
    border:none;
}

.calendar td.button {
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
    border:none;
    padding:3px;
}

.calendar td.button div { 
    font-size:14px;
}

.calendar td.button div:first-child {
    font-size:13px;
}

.calendar table td.wn {
    border-left:1px solid #CCC;
}

.calendar thead .weekend {
 color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, editing all the CSS files in /public_html/js/calendar will fix the problem.

You have to edit the color code anywhere where it mentions weekend to:

## 000

Answer (score 0):

try .calendar tbody .weekend insted of ”thead”